# yield not working with custom enumerable/enumerator

Tags: c#, yield

Recently I started a hobby project to rewrite the collections structure, starting by removing the not generic `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable`, making new IEnumerator/IEnumerable base interfaces. I quickly ran in a problem with yield when creating a conversion between my new enumerable interface and the normal one.

My `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>` are exactly the same as the normal ones, except they don't inherit from the not generic ones.
Why is yield not working with my interfaces? `foreach` does work with my interfaces.

Example:

```
public static System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> ToMSEnumerable(this My.IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable) // enumerating my enumerable works
    {
        yield return item; // this works
    }
}

public static My.IEnumerable<T> ToMyEnumerable(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable) // obviously work
    {
        yield return item; // this is where its not working.
                           // I haven't touched this in a few day, so I don't remember
                           // the error message
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious - what does your `My.IEnumerable<T>` do differently than the standard `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @Enigmativity It doesn't have the non-generic `GetEnumerator()`

Comment: And why is that important?

Comment: @Enigmativity users of the interface wouldn't have to implement it? Better type safety?

Comment: Why do users need to implement it anyway? It would be a very rare thing to implement considering the number of built-in collections and operators.

Comment: @Enigmativity It wouldn't be rare if I wanted to rewrite everything as a hobby project

Answer (score 7):

Your `foreach` works because [`foreach` uses duck-typing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288257.aspx) - anything with a `GetEnumerator` method will work. This is because `foreach` is older than generics, so that was the only reasonable way to implement it and get strong typing.

However, iterator methods are *not* older than generics, so `yield` was designed with `IEnumerable<T>` in mind. Therefore, `yield` **requires**:

> - The return type must be `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator`, or `IEnumerator<T>`.

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

Naturally, your home-built enumerable class is not in the list.

Comment: The really "cool" thing about for each is the type `GetEnumerator()` returns does not need to be a `IEnumerator` all, It checks for is a public method named `MoveNext()` and a public property named `Current`, if it has those two things it will happily work.

Comment: Nice answer. Consider editing the question to add correct error message so it does not look like candidate for deletion.

Comment: I imagined such. But seems a little inconsistent with the rest of "duck-typing" around collections.